# programmatically adding a layout to phonegap as banner

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have layout like this

```html
<ir.adad.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        token="hadi" />
```

and i want to add it to my phone-gap application onCreate method. so far i have written the code and extend Droidgap but i don't know how to turn my above code to java code for adding this layout to my app

Comment: You should try with an existing/your own plugin. If you are doing it with AdMob, you can take a look at https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova.

Comment: I'm using eclipse and i do not want to use any plug-in. i know that layout can be written in java. i just don't know how!

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own plugin. You can take a look on how to do it in the link I left you before.